# How to remove Global Secondary Index from DynamoDb by removing it from CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I have a table with GlobalSecondaryIndexes specified in the CloudFormation Template.

I want to remove this indexes from DynamoDb by removing them from CloudFormation Template, but I have an error during deploying: "Property AttributeDefinitions is inconsistent with the KeySchema of the table and the secondary indexes".

Comment: does the DynamoDB contain content ?

Comment: @jarnohenneman yes, it does.

Comment: Then my guess is that that is the reason why you can't change it through CF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would help if you posted the CF Template, but I'll give it a stab anyway..

The AttributeDefinitions in the definition can only be for attributes in the Key Schema or indexes that exist, because DynamoDB is schemaless.

If you are removing the GSIs, then you need to remove those attribute definitions as well (unless they exist in the Base Table's Key Schema or LSIs).

HTH